# Macbook Pro 2011 Snow Leopard Boot Camp with Parallels Desktop 8

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, partition, parallels-desktop

Quick question in response to a very thorough [bootcamp post already on this forum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/macbook-air-lion-windows-7-boot-camp-shared-partition/98692#98692).

For anybody that has a working Mac, Windows and Shared partition ... is the Boot Camp partition recognised by Parallels Desktop?

I ask because I wanted to make use of Parallels Desktop integration feautres, but despite getting a working multi-boot between Mac and Windows with additional shared partition ... Parallels Desktop would not find Boot Camp, but would try installing itself onto the Windows partition - and fail).

If I removed the shared partition and Windows to the default single Mac partition, then partition split using Boot Camp Assisitant, Parallels Desktop would recognize Boot Camp and install itself onto Windows partition properly (only I then have no shared partition).

Soon as I try breaking up partitions beyond this Boot Camp Assistant default (despite getting multi-boot working) Parallels seems unable to use the Windows partition (always hangs and gives various boot errors) though the Windows partition will multi-boot.

The only way I have been able to check that Boot Camp is setup right for Parallels Desktop integration, is to go into Parallels Desktop and create new file ... Boot Camp partition option and icon are then available. If Boot Camp is there in Parallels Desktop, then I can load and use that partition with Parallels Desktop. Otherwise, Parallels Desktop fails to integrate despite having a working bootable Windows partition.

Reminder to self: working multi boot != working boot camp

Ultimately, I'm back to starting with default Mac partition and Boot Camp Asssitant-created Windows partition without additional shared partition. This works for Parallels Desktop integration each time, but cannot fathom how to then create a shared partition.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution and can confirm that the bootcamp works with Parallels (with additional shared drive): https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3293948